# how to report pytest fixture value in tests output

Tags: python, pytest

is there a way to report pytest fixture value in tests output?

To demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve - typically you could parametrize the fixture and use *id* to describe the parameter, what then would be showed in the test output. However the fixture output might be result of complex logic, and you might want to show not just the parameter id but something more specific, based on actual output of the fixture

```
connection_object = ConnectionObject()
connection_object.name = 'Undefined_name'

@pytest.fixture(params=[connection_object], ids = [connection_object.name])
def fixture_test_connection(request):
    # some fixture logic , setting up connection object, e.g. opening connection to a specific db based on config file
    connection_object.name = 'my_specific_connection_name'
    return connection_object

def test_smt(fixture_test_connection):
    # test smt
```

after executing, this is then displayed as  `<path_to_file>::test_smt[Undefined_name] PASSED`

what I would like to see is
`<path_to_file>::test_smt[my_specific_connection_name] PASSED`

I tried setting `id = <callable>` where callable is function that returns connection_object.name but it still returns original 'Undefined_name' rather than  specific one.
The issue is really about reporting, any way to conveniently report my_specific_connection_name along test results would do.